# Call Constructor of Parent Class and get return value

Tags: c#, .net, abstract-class

I have an interface called **iParser** which is implemented by **AbstractParser** now i inherit this class.

I process a string and get the **parts** in the Abstract class.How can i get the return value in the child class **ImageParser**?

```
interface iParser
{
    RepositoryItem GetRepositoryItem(CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e);
}

public abstract class AbstractParser:iParser
{
    String[] parts;
    Dictionary<int, RepositoryItem> riObjectCache = new Dictionary<int, RepositoryItem>();
    public AbstractParser(String iDecodeStr)
    {
        parts = SimpleParser.parseCommandLine(iDecodeStr);
    }

    public RepositoryItem GetRepositoryItem(CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

class ImageParser : AbstractParser
{
    Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    Dictionary<string, Bitmap> newdict = new Dictionary<string, Bitmap>();
    string defaultvalue = null;
    public ImageParser(string istring) : base(istring)
    {
```

Comment: Your base class has to expose `parts` in some way or other. There's no point in it even having the field if it doesn't make use of it.

Comment: make `parts` protected on your abstract class, so you can use it in`ImageParser` class.

Comment: @rraszewski How?

Comment: `protected  String[] parts;` in `AbstractParser` and then you can call `this.parts` in `ImageParser`. But as @JonSkeet mentioned please make sure that you really need that field. Maybe you should create a method instead that returns `String[]`.

Comment: @rraszewski I think i will add another method,the constructor is little confusing.

Comment: If your `GetRepositoryItem` in that `AbstractParser` should not work, then declare it as abstract (just `public abstract RepositoryItem GetRepositoryItem(CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e);`). This means that derived classes *must* implement it.